# The best applications of the Poincaré-Bendixson theorem

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis, gt.geometric-topology, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

I'm reading about the Poincaré-Bendixson theorem in the plane, I really liked the theorem. I have seen common applications in Sotomayor and Perko's book. But I would like to know what other applications outside of the common literature (mentioned above) there are, I mean interesting applications that you create valuable. If possible, mention a reference to your example. Thank you very much.

Comment: this is really way too unfocused for this site.

Comment: A related question on math.stackexchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326351/nice-corollaries-to-poincar%C3%A9-bendixson-theorem

Comment: Does periodicity for solutions of the Lotka-Volterra equations count? Though there are more elementary arguments for that.

Comment: Now I am busy with work, later I will edit my question to list all the applications that I have managed to find along with your reference, I think that way you could help me much better.